# react native what to use to write a text with '<'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, text

It realy is a simple question but it's been 10 mn and I can't seems to find how to formulate this to have an answer on the web.
I have a  Click on <>  and I want to write the '<' caracter.
What do I need to write before it? (got Syntax error: Unexpected token)

Comment: have you tried to put it in a String Template literals {\`<\`}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to do it like this
`<Text>{"<"}</Text>`

Comment: Thanks! I was really ashamed to ask this question